# What does list comprehension "counts[num]=counts.get(num,0)+1" mean?

Tags: python

I know the code `counts[num]=counts.get(num,0)+1` is a kind of list comprehension. However, I don't understand what exactly does it mean. Could any Python experts explain this to me?

```
fname=input('Enter the file name: ')
fhand = open(fname)
biglist=[]
counts=dict()
count=0
secondlist=[]
for line in fhand:
    line=line.strip()
    word=line.split()
    if len(word)<1:
        continue
    if word[0]!='From':
        continue
    words=word[5]
    words=words.split(':')
    num=words[0]
    **counts[num]=counts.get(num,0)+1**

counts=counts.items()
counts_sorted=sorted(counts)

for k,v in counts_sorted:
    print(k,v)
```

Comment: Well, first of all it's _not_ a list comprehension

Comment: which part of that statement do you not understand? It's all pretty standard Python syntax, with a call to a built-in method.

Comment: Please don't add junk content to your question to get around our quality filters. They're there to help _you_ as much as us. Asking a high-quality question is the best way to increase your chances of getting a useful answer. See [ask].

Comment: Please add text that explains your code and your problem in greater detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***List Comprehension***

This is not list comprehension.

List comprehesion for example:

```
lst2 = [x for x in lst1 if x % 2 == 0]
```

Where `lst1` is a list and we filter in only values that are even `if x % 2 == 0` and assign it to list `lst2`.

***Meaning of `counts[num]=counts.get(num,0)+1`***

1. `counts.get(num,0)` get value of `num` key from `counts` dictionary, if key not exists return `0`
2. So `counts[num]=counts.get(num,0)+1` would result in increasing `counts[num]` by one (and if not exists would by set to one)

Comment: Actually, I found the **counts[num]=counts.get(num,0)+1** is a smart expression of 
if num not in counts:
        counts[num]=1
    elese:
        counts[num]=counts[num]+1

Comment: @PhilipXiao that exactly what I wrote at "Meaning of counts[num]=counts.get(num,0)+1" second bullet :)

Comment: Sometimes, I need to see the exact (silly)syntax to know what exactly happens. I know my question may sound like a dumb question but as a Python novice with 10 days of study experiences, there is a long long journey that I  need to go.  Thank you to explain to me.